# How do I upgrade revision in emberjs DS.Store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am new to emberJS and I was wondering one thing about the DS.Store revision value.

From the documentation and [Katz's peepcode video](https://peepcode.com/products/play-by-play-wycats-ii-emberjs) (which I highly recommend), you get a nice little error message in the console when the revision is too high, for instance:

```
App.store = DS.Store.create({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
    namespace: 'api'
  })
});
```

Could return:

```
Uncaught Error: Error: The Ember Data library has had breaking API changes since the last time you updated the library. Please review the list of breaking changes at https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/BREAKING_CHANGES.md, then update your store's `revision` property to 4
```

I understand that, when this message is displayed, you have got to refer back to the [breaking change page of the ember-data source code](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/BREAKING_CHANGES.md) but I am really confused as of what it is I need to look into.

For the **Revision 5** (the revision I am trying to upgrade too I guess), there are so many things and none seems to really apply to my app.

So, someone might be able to provide me with some guidance as far as what's the methodology around upgrading revision. Do you need to address the revision notes and then up the revision number (then repeat) OR does it mean that something has been broken and you need to use that revision number for the time being?

Sorry about the lengthy post, but I am trying to get out of my own confusion :)

Thanks!

Comment: So, to clarify about the issue I was having, it seemed that the ember-data that was embedded into the ember-rails gem is outdated.
Checking the **DS.CURRENT_API_REVISION** in the console helped into understanding which version or ember-data I was using.
Consequently, I had to [download and compile the ember-data from the github repo](https://github.com/emberjs/data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nice to see you're giving ember a shot!

So that error message works the other way around - it's complaining that you're revision (5) is too low for the version of ember-data.js. Ember is forcing you to manually update your rev number to match the one that is current. Ember-data library is changing so fast, they want to make everyone is aware of breaking changes. If you are building something new just set the revision to whatever is current (as of today that's 11)

That peepcode video was good but is way out of date. Trying to follow along while using current version of ember is not going to work. Ember has changed a lot in the last several weeks and most of the tutorials/etc you'll find online have not caught up. Right now the best source of info is the guides: http://emberjs.com/guides

Also I'd recommend watching Tom Dale and Yehuda Katz presentation at Seattle Ember.js meetup last month: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_6yMxU-_ARs

Comment: Thanks @Michael mmm, so I put revision: 11 and it complains and asks me to "downgrade" to revision 4 and fix my bugs before moving up, right?

I somehow got a bunch of breakthroughs watching the video and see Katz coding though...

And, we should get coffee... ;)

Answer (score 0):

As Michael said the tutorial is a bit out of date. I updated to the actual version of the libs (jquery, handlebars, ember and ember-data). Current revision for DS is 12

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
adapter: 'DS.FixutreAdapter'
```

});